# Debugging QML stored in qrc within shared library

Tags: qt, debugging, qml

By architecture of application I have core executable that is loading it's plugins with help of QPlugin (described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#the-low-level-api-extending-qt-applications)).

I have added .qrc file containing all resources (images, etc.) and .qml files to each plugin, so it is [built within it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library)

I have managed to call and execute .qml files from this plugins.

The problem is: debugger completly ignore all breakpoints set from QtCreator to this .qml files (though I see "Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment" in console output)

So is it possible to connect QtCreator's QML debugger to .qml that is stored in .qrc that is built within shared library plugin?