# Why QML debugging is not working when resource file .qrc is imported from a static library

Tags: debugging, qml, qt-creator

I have a set of .qrc files populated inside a static library project.
In the application project I initialize the resource as follows:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(base);
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(images);

...
```

The application runs and correctly loads all the .qrc files. When I put a breakpoint in any .qml file defined inside the resources the application stops but Qt Creator is not able to point me to the line where the break resides. If I click on resume (F5) the application resumes correctly.
The debug expression evaluator shows just a spinning wheel when the breakpoint is hit, till execution is resumed:
[image]

When the breakpoint is hit (I'm sure it is), the IDE does not show the yellow arrow inside the red circle:
[image]

I followed the indications from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library), enabled QML debugging, set also:

```
CONFIG += declarative_debug
CONFIG += qml_debug
```

in my .pro. No luck unfortunately.

Versions

- QtCreator: 8.0.0 Based on Qt 6.3.1 (GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1), x86_64)
- Qt: 5.15.2 GCC 64 bits

Can you help me understanding what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Qt? If you set your breakpoint inside a JS section in a QML file, it should indeed stop there in the debugger. Can we see the line where you put your breakpoint?

Comment: @mzimmers: added the info into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question asked here:
[Debugging QML stored in qrc within shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488879/debugging-qml-stored-in-qrc-within-shared-library)

I ended up with the following scheme:

- resource file NOT imported in shared library
- resource file imported in application project

Since I have multiple applications using the shared resource, I had to organize project structure in this way:

root

- resources
- res1 folder
- res1.qrc //where res1 folder is added as a directory
- res2 folder
- res2,
- ...
- project1.pro //using res*.qrc
- project2.pro //using res*.qrc
- ...

this is the only scheme I found that satisfy the following constraints:

- contents added to .qrc must be in the same folder or subfolders of .qrc file
- directory added to resources should be showed with simple name in the QtCreator project pane (e.g. `res.qrc`, not `/very/long/absolute/path/res.qrc`)
- contents in resource file should be showed with a simple name as well (e.g. `res.qrc/res/myitem.qml` not `res.qrc/../../very/long/path/to/myitem.qml`) and also new resources should not require aliases (via scripts or manual insertion) to ensure a frictionless development

Best regards